# Adding Category Pages - CPT - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type and I'm trying to display a category page so when you click on a standard link to a category, you will see all of the posts in that category... It seems simple, and I have looked at the Wordpress hierarchy, but I can't figure out which template files I need to create...

I currently have this page pulling through my custom fields: http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/brand/ NOT looping through custom post types. The code is essentially this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: Main Category Template
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>



<!-- Featured Image ===========================================  -->

<div class="image-test-container">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

    // Get the post thumbnail URL
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
  } else {

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">.featured-image{
    display:none;
    }</style>
    <?php
  } ?>


    <div id="absolute1111" style=" background: url(<?php echo $feat_image; ?>);">
        <div class="centerd1111">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>





<!-- Page Content ===========================================  -->

<div class="container">

    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="">

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="level-two-intro-text">
        <p><?php the_field('intro_text'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="level-two-sub-title block__title">
        <?php the_field('sub_title'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>





<!-- Areas ===========================================  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">

        <?php if(get_field('areas')): ?>


                <?php while(has_sub_field('areas')): ?>


                    <div class="single-area-item six columns">
                        <p> <img src="<?php the_sub_field('area_icon'); ?>" style="width:100%;"> <p>
                        <h2> <?php the_sub_field('area_title'); ?> </h2> 
                        <p> <?php the_sub_field('area_info'); ?> <p>
                        <div class="area-button"><a href="<?php the_sub_field('button_target'); ?>" class="btn btn--dark-blue" role="button"><?php the_sub_field('button_text'); ?></a></div>
                    </div>


                <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

However, When I click on the Portfolio button under each category, I would like it to display a page of that category...

I could make this work by creating a single template page for each category and looping through and display all posts within a specific category, but that seems like the wrong way - I'm thinking there should be one template to show the category I have just clicked on...

I think I'm getting a little confused to be honest. Thanks for looking :)

+++ EDIT +++

Here's the code I'm using for the custom post type...

```
register_post_type('portfolio', $args);

// Portfolio Categories
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x('Portfolio Categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'     => _x('Portfolio Category', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'search_items'      => __('Search Portfolio Categories'),
    'all_items'         => __('All Portfolio Categories'),
    'parent_item'       => __('Parent Portfolio Category'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Portfolio Category:'),
    'edit_item'         => __('Edit Portfolio Category'),
    'update_item'       => __('Update Portfolio Category'),
    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Portfolio Category'),
    'new_item_name'     => __('New Portfolio Category Name'),
    'menu_name'         => __('Portfolio Category'),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'category'),
);

register_taxonomy('portfolio-category', array('portfolio'), $args);
```

Comment: Hi... are you using the default category for custom post type too? or custom taxonomy?

Comment: It's custom - it's called portfolio-category, so I could keep it separate from the blog and other items I have...

Comment: I'll add the CPT text to the question if that helps...

Comment: Ok so you first want to get the custom-category link on the button and then you want to configure that category page template?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add an archive template for your custom categories. The easiest way is to copy archive.php in your theme folder, and give it the correct name.

According to the template heirarchy (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), you'll need to use the filename 'taxonomy-portfolio-category.php'

If you want to style each category differently, you can create files with the name "taxonomy-portfolio-category-{categoryslug}.php"

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mzalewski1 - However, the links that are supposed to link to the category links are just urls the user will be inserting into a Custom Field... will this still work and what URL will they need to put in?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file  `'taxonomy-portfolio-category.php'`

your custom taxonomy code put here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi first create a page named `taxonomy-portfolio-category.php` and place below code , it is a sample code, you can edit it according to your theme

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php /* How to display posts of the Gallery format. The gallery category is the old way. */ ?>
<div class="test">
<?php 
echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
echo "<div>".get_the_excerpt()."</div>";
?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) - What target would I need to use for the portfolio buttons here: http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/brand/ ? And how will that page know which category I'm clicking on?

Comment: Can you please provide me the loop code of those portfolio buttons? And that page automatically detect the category and work accordingly.

Comment: I'm not actually looping through the buttons - they are just custom fields for that page, where the user can add the URL target...

Comment: Ok then please go to  your taxonomy listing page and click on any view link,

Check where that links are targeted to, and you can use those links

May be you can go to that page by 
http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=portfolio-category&post_type=portfolio

Comment: I don't think that works, @ashkar, it just links to the admin page? - I can create 'category' pages in the menu section, but when I create one of these, it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: or copy your category.php file and paste it inside taxonomy-portfolio-category.php,

It go to any portfolio-category item and check.

Comment: I actually don't have a category file, but i will have a look for how to create one! :)

Comment: We don't want to create it. It will be there automatically. Check if archive.php is there. If so copy its content to taxonomy-portfolio-category.php, that is enough.

Comment: If still confused, please refer this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/taxonomy-archives-list-posts-by-taxonomys-terms--cms-20045